# Unable to save slideshow video in iOS Photos app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, slideshow

I am trying to save one of those auto-generated slideshow/video in iOS Photos app. The video plays fine on my iPhone. I open it, then share icon, then "Save Video". A dialog box comes up that says "Preparing Video..." with a progress circle underneath. Normally, the circle begins to fill up and the video is saved. In this case, it just stays as a gray circle. Several minutes later there is still no progress. Is there any way to resolve this?

I am using iPhone 13 with more than 30 GB free and the latest iOS (15.5). I tried force-quitting the Photos app and restarting the phone. I also tried "Add to Shared Album" and "Save to Files" instead of "Save Video". Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the slideshow and your internet speed, it may take longer for the video to load (the slideshow is most likely a large file). I've had a similar issue where the progress bar for saving a video doesn't move. In my case, the progress bar didn't move until 10+ minutes later and then the progress bar immediately went green. I would suggest waiting for a longer time period (try 15 minutes) and see if it loads. During this time just leave your phone open on that loading screen and wait. If it still does not load, make sure to check **Settings** > **Photos** > scroll down to **Cellular Data** > make sure Cellular Data is turned on. Sometimes cellular data is preferred when downloading things if the cellular data is faster than your wifi speed.

Comment: I was doing it with WiFi, so connection speed shouldn't be too much of an issue. I tried waiting for over an hour and there was no progress.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8509461) on Apple.com that says "You can't save the Memories slideshow.  Since it uses the slideshow features in Photos just create an album from the images you put in the memory and create your own slideshow.  That one can be exported out as a video file. " I thought it is still possible to save those slideshow videos. I suggest taking a look at the thread. Also, I have heard that having the phone in "Low Power Mode" can cause issues for downloading photos/videos. Otherwise, if none of these work try contacting Apple Support directly